# Node.js and MySQL function usage

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

New to node.js and just cant figure out how to do the following:

I have this on my db module:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var MY_DATABASE='nodejs_mysql';

var client = mysql.createClient({
user: 'root',
password: 'root',
});
```

and im building this table:

```
client.query(
'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE '+USER+
'(username VARCHAR(255), '+
'password VARCHAR(255), '+
'name VARCHAR(255), '+
'picture VARCHAR(255), '+
'PRIMARY KEY(username))'
);
```

and later on, i want to perform this:

```
client.query('select username, password from ' + USER + 'where username=?',[req.body.username] , 'AND password=?', [req.body.password] 
function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
   //some actions performed here
});
```

all of those are in the same dataBase.js file.

how can i send username and password from another file named: server.js

as parameters to the query written above and get a certain value back?

is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not quiet sure what you exactly wanted to do, but at first glance it looks like you need to read about node's [modules](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) and maybe `module.exports` (http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#module.exports)

Comment: what i meant is to ask is it ok to "rap" the last part of code in a function which receives params and returns a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I get it now. You create temporary table in `dataBase.js` and want to perform query in this table in request handler in `server.js`. If that's it, you should consider following aproach:

```js
// dataBase.js

var mysql = require('mysql');
var MY_DATABASE='nodejs_mysql';

// connect to database
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
});

// create temporary table
client.query(
  'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE '+USER+
  '(username VARCHAR(255), '+
  'password VARCHAR(255), '+
  'name VARCHAR(255), '+
  'picture VARCHAR(255), '+
  'PRIMARY KEY(username))'
);

// that's what I think you need. And yes, it looks like "a good to rap" for me.
module.exports.getInfoFromTemporaryTable : function( username, password, callback) {
  client.query(
    'select username, password from ' + USER + 'where username=?',
    [req.body.username] , 'AND password=?', [req.body.password], 
    callback
  );
}
```

The only thing I can't figure out is where you get `USER` variable from. Pay attention to this moment. Maybe pass it to `getInfoFromTemporaryTable()` function.

```js
// server.js
var db = require('./lib/dataBase');

app.get(someRoute, function(req, res) {
  db.getInfoFromTemporaryTable( req.body.username, req.body.password,
    function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        // handle errors or something
        return;
      }

      // do what you need to do, using results you got from temp table
  });
});
```

I'm not familiar with MySQL module you using, so above code is more like a general idea of what you need to implement. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! about the USER variable, its not a variable its a table which is not written here...:) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> how can i send username and password from another file named: server.js
>
> as parameters to the query written above and get a certain value back?

Use the `exports` object. See **[here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/modules.html)** for more information on NodeJS's module system.

```
// server.js
exports.username = function {
  return "foo";
};

exports.password = function {
  return "bar";
};

// database.js
require('./server.js');
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user:     server.username,   // exports.username in server.js
  password: server.password,   // exports.password in server.js
});
```

Comment: i think i was misunderstood here... i want to get values to the query:  
client.query('select username, password from ' + USER + 'where username=?',[req.body.username] , 'AND password=?', [req.body.password]
and return some value... i think that your answer will not do that.
i need to add some more queries and let them return some more values...
is it clearer now?

Comment: You want to get values for query from where exactly? Other module? Other DB query? As far as I understand, the source is temporary table created in dataBase.js file. When request comes you want query some values from this temporary table and use them in request handler. Am I right?

Comment: @elmigranto i want to get values for query from other module,yes.
is it good to "rap" the last query in a function which receives params
and returns some things?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you splitting your query up?

```
// server.js
exports.username = "Your username.";
exports.password = "Your password.";

// dataBase.js
// ... mysql connection setup ...
var server = require("./server");
client.query('SELECT username, password FROM `' + USER + '` WHERE username=? AND password=?',
  [server.username, server.password],
  function (err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    // ... some actions performed here ...
  }
);
```

I'm not exactly sure what you were asking, but I think this should at least get you closer to your answer.